# Mustache JS: fill multiple divs with different content

Tags: javascript, mustache

I'm working with Mustache JS for the first time, and have a question about the best way to achieve what I want. I have the following page, with a couple of divs that are setup the same way, but need to get different content.

[image: my page]

This is what I got so far:

```
<script id="mustacheTemplate1" type="text/template">
    <div class="{{box_cols}}">
        <div class="box box-{{box_color}}">
            <h2 class="box-title">{{box_title}}</h2>
            {{box_content}}
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

<div class="target-output1"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var template1 = $("#mustacheTemplate1").html();
var targetContainer = $(".target-output1");

var shows = { 
    "box_cols": "col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6",
    "box_color": "blue",
    "box_title": "Title goes here",
    "box_content": "Content goes here",
};

var html = Mustache.to_html(template1, shows);

$(targetContainer).html(html);  
</script>
```

This fills my first div, which is what I want. I could repeat this and duplicate target-output1 to target-output2, target-output3, etc. But I was wondering if there is a better or more efficient way?

I don't know if it matters, but I'm going to use Google Charts in some of the divs content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a loop assuming you have all divs you need to fill with generated content

```
var template1 = $("#mustacheTemplate1").html();

[
  { 
    "box_cols": "col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6",
    "box_color": "blue",
    "box_title": "Title goes here",
    "box_content": "Content goes here",
  },
  { 
    "box_cols": "col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6",
    "box_color": "red",
    "box_title": "Another Title",
    "box_content": "Totally different content goes here",
  }
  //, ... etc
].forEach(function(data, i) {
  $('.target-output' + (i+1)).html(Mustache.to_html(template1, data))
})
```